# IIS SSL Certificate binding (Get binding info)

Tags: powershell, iis

I have several websites on an IIS server all listening on port 8080, and all with the same certificate in use (a generic * one for testing purposes).

When I run `Get-ChildItem IIS:\SslBindings` I'm presented with:

```
IP Address          Port   Host Name        Store            Sites
----------          ----   ---------        -----            -----
0.0.0.0             8080                    MY               Site1
                                                             Site2
                                                             Site3
```

If I do

```
Get-ChildItem IIS:\SSLBindings | ? { $_.Sites -eq Site1 }
```

I get exactly the same result.

Is there a method that tells me JUST what certificate Site1 is using? Maybe a `Get-ItemProperty` thing? I'm using:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Site1']/bindings" -Name "Collection").bindingInformation
```

to get port information, but can't seem to figure out what the thumbprint ID of the certificate assigned to this one site is.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.binding?view=iis-dotnet Instead of reading `bindingInformation` you should read other properties of the Binding object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from Lex Li and a fresh pair of eyes sat next to me, was able to figure it out.

```
( ( Get-ItemProperty -Filter"/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Site1']/Bindings" -name Collection ).CertificateHash )
```